# What happens with LinkedHashMap elements when I convert them to Set?

Tags: java

```
LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> h;
```

It contains:

```
key 1 : value A, B, C, D
2 : E,F
3 : G
```

I don't quite understand the Set interface. Maybe a little visualization would help. Please help me to visualize how would all these elements inside LinkedHashMap look like once I convert them into Set?

```
Set set = h.entrySet();
```

Sorry, maybe my question is a little obscure. I will try to sharpen it as the thread develops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry-set of a `Map` is the **set of entries in the map**.

An entry in a map is a mapping from key to value. In your case where the map is of type `...<String, ArrayList<String>>`, an single entry is a pair of a `String` (the key) and an `ArrayList<String>` (the value).

The following snippet may shed some light on this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> map =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

map.put("1", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
map.put("2", Arrays.asList("E", "F"));
map.put("3", Arrays.asList("G"));

System.out.println(map.entrySet());
System.out.println(map.entrySet().getClass());
```

**Output:**

```
[1=[A, B, C], 2=[E, F], 3=[G]]     # All entries (key/value pairs)
class java.util.HashMap$EntrySet   # This particular entry set class.
```

In this case for instance, the entry set is actually an inner class of `HashMap`, named `EntrySet`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference between the interface and the class... What types implement Set interface?

Comment: @Prostak, any class declared as `class SomeClass implements Set` (or any class that extends a class that implements `Set`).

Answer (score 1):

The `entrySet()` is just the entries (key-value pairs) in the map. It would help you to look at the type returned by `entrySet()`, which is `Set<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>>` in your example. See the [Map.Entry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) javadoc.

Also note that the map is not *converted to* an entry set--rather, the entry set is a view of the entries in the map.

As far as what a `Set` is: it's a set of elements that are each unique according to some definition of unique (`equals`/`hashCode` for most `Set`s, `Comparable`/`Comparator` for `SortedSet`s). Since a `Map` can have at most one value mapped to a single key, each key-value entry is guaranteed to be unique.